# What is the point of revealing the end of time to Daniel only to conceal it?

Tags: time, daniel-book-of, latid-lavo-future

The book of Daniel chapter 12 seems to provide Daniel with information related to the end of time only to then instruct Daniel to keep the information secret (12:4). Daniel then asks when the end of time will be and is given more cryptic information. To this day no one has been able to accurately ascertain the meaning of the information imparted. My question is what then is the point of providing this information at all? If God does not want people to know when the end of time will be then why reveal it and then hide it within the text instead of simply omitting it or telling Daniel not to write down his experience.

Answer (score 1):

Our vision of torah is limited to our own temporary mortal limitations. This same torah is being studied in heaven, and also we will receive new and deeper understanding of Torah after our redemption.
Torah must be all encompassing.

Just imagine our DNA would have been a fraction of it's size just because we didn't understand it?!

Everything in Torah MUST be there. Our final redemption will come about ONLY because it has been recorded in the Torah. Hashem simply doesn't want us to know the exact time just yet, but since the Torah is the blue print of all of creation through all of time, everything must be at least cryptically recorded in it.

Comment: it is actually a full answer to the question.

Comment: I highly recommend explaining your answer better. I see how it's an answer, but I didn't realize how until I read it a few times.

Comment: i added a paragraph. i hope its clearer now.

Comment: This is an interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the information is provided so that when the "end time" arrives we will be able to see that it had been predicted. (The "end time" is not the end of humanity, it is the end of the exile and hardship, the galus; this is what is described in the prophecy preceding the verse in question.) I think this is what the [verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.12.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) means by עַד־עֵ֣ת קֵ֑ץ, until, but not including, the end time. The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.12.4?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en) explains the verse that "at the end time the doubt will be removed."

Comment: What's the value in that?

Answer (score 0):

So that it should be more  tangible. When you know someone was promised  to someone else  even if you don't share that information the fact that it happened  makes it more of a reality.

Comment: then why not share the idea without specific dates?